# How do I terminate Aptitude safely

Tags: keyboard, tmux, signals, aptitude, ncurses

I have a TMux session with Aptitude open.
The Aptitude process has been "killed" several times with STOP/CONT.
Now it doesn't react to the Q key. Instead a 'q' is printed on the top-left corner of the tty.
Writing 'q' to `/proc/.../fd/0` produces the same effect.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [aptitude source](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/aptitude), it installs a signal handler for `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGHUP` (as well as `SIGILL`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS` and `SIGABRT`).  That only removes a temporary directory.  It does the same thing using `atexit` when exiting normally.

Bear in mind that `aptitude` is a *front-end* to `apt`.  If `aptitude` is not *doing* anything, then one method of killing it should do as well as another.  `SIGSTOP` doesn't do that.  It suspends the process.  That signal is handled by ncurses, which by the way installs handlers for `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` to cleanup the screen (see [*Signal Handlers*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) discussion in the `initscr` manual page).  Given that ncurses does its handlers after `aptitude`, it seems that the `atexit` code to cleanup the temporary directory is what `aptitude` *uses*.

From the description, `aptitude` has been stopped/started and it is for whatever reason not responding.  From another terminal, you should be able to use `kill`, sending `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` to kill the process.

On the other hand, **`apt`** does the work.  You may have to repair *its* state.  The question *[How to safely abort apt-get install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253925/how-to-safely-abort-apt-get-install)* mentions one way to repair the dpkg database:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```